# Generating JWT with Ruby for iTunes Connect API

Tags: ruby, jwt, app-store-connect

I'm trying to generate a token to sign my requests to the iTunes Connect API. That's my Ruby file:

```
require "jwt"
require 'openssl'

ISSUER_ID = "my issuer string"
KEY_ID = "my key id string"

key_file = File.read('my p8 file containing my private key') # Located at the same folder than my ruby file
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key_file)

payload = {
      'iss': ISSUER_ID,
      'exp': 1528408800,
      'aud': 'appstoreconnect-v1'
  }

header = {
      'alg': 'ES256',
      'kid': KEY_ID,
      'typ': 'JWT'
  }

  jwt = JWT.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='ES256', header)
  puts jwt
```

If I run this file `ruby jwt.rb` I get the following output:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt/algos/ecdsa.rb:15:in sign': undefined method group' for # (NoMethodError)
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt/signature.rb:35:in sign'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt/encode.rb:39:in encoded_signature'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt/encode.rb:47:in encode_segments'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt/encode.rb:20:in initialize'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt.rb:21:in new'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/jwt-2.1.0/lib/jwt.rb:21:in encode'
>       from jwt.rb:22:in '

From the console output it is hard to tell what's failing, but if I were to use RS256 as algorithm and omit the header, the script generates a token successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's caused by using RSA key with ECDSA encryption algorithm. Either use `RS256` algo instead of `ES256`, or use `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` instead of `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` (for that you'd probably need a new private key, though).

Comment: It is required to use ES256, so I guess I have to stick to that. What do you mean by "or that you'd probably need a new private key, though". Can I not use my downloaded private key?

Comment: Well, I don't know how iTunes key generation stuff works. If you have generated an RSA key pair and uploaded your public key to iTunes -- then you need to generate an ECDSA key and re-upload. If you download the private key from iTunes -- then it's probably already an ECDSA key, just use `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` and hopefully it will work. :-)

Comment: I generated a private key in iTunes and downloaded it. The thing is that `OpenSSL::PKey::EC` is still complaining: >in `initialize': unknown curve name (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- (OpenSSL::PKey::ECError)

Comment: Then it's an RSA key and you need to use RS256. Where is the requirement for ES256 coming from?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

Comment: I found the root problem. My p8 file got corrupted and therefore was not able to generate a new EC key. Now is solved and I'm able to generate a token (still failing to fetch from iTunes but that's a different issue). So your answer indeed solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is `Apnotic` gem, which implements Apple push notifications in modern Apple way:
`HTTP2.0` + `JWT` + `p8`.

Probably, you could find the solution in its [ProviderToken class](https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic/blob/master/lib/apnotic/provider_token.rb).